# "Cannot convert value of type 'AVAudioPlayer.Type' to expected argument type"

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, xcode9

I'm having trouble with the function audioPlayerDidFinish playing. I have added the AVAudioPlayerDelegate to my view controller class and defined the function. When I call the function I get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'AVAudioPlayer.Type' to expected argument type" What am I doing wrong? Let me know if I need to add more code for you to see.

```
    func buttonPressed() {
    if currentSound == sound {
        currentSound = "None"
        activateBlankCircle()
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
    else {
        currentSound = sound
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        activateRedCircle()
        playSound()
        audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(AVAudioPlayer, successfully: Bool)
        //Cannot convert value of type 'AVAudioPlayer.Type' to expected argument type

    }

}
```

Comment: If you explain more about what you are trying to do and why are you implementing `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying`, answers will probably be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate methods should not be called by the delegate itself.

`audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` here is a delegate method. You are supposed to implement it (which you have) and set `self` as the audio player's delegate. The method will be called by the `AVAudioPlayer` at an appropriate time i.e. when it finishes playing a sound.

So you should remove the call to `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` and everything should work fine. From the looks for it, you are implementing a start/stop playing button. If you want to do something when the player finishes playing, you can set `self` as the `audioPlayer.delegate` in `viewDidLoad`. And the method will be called when it finishes playing a sound.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much!! How do I mark this question as answered and give you credit for answering it? :D