# SharingMusicPlayer.swift:12:79: Cannot convert value of type 'AVAudioPlayer.Type' to expected argument type 'AVAudioPlayer'

Tags: swift, xcode, singleton

This is what I have in my singleton:

```
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

class SharingMusicPlayer {
    static let sharingMusicPlayer = SharingMusicPlayer(backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer)
    let backgroundMusicPlayer : AVAudioPlayer

    private init(backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer) {
        self.backgroundMusicPlayer = backgroundMusicPlayer
    }

    func playMusic() {
        // open and play an mp3 file...
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
SharingMusicPlayer.swift:12:79: Cannot convert value of type 'AVAudioPlayer.Type' to expected argument type 'AVAudioPlayer'
```

Here is another post I have investigated but the solution does not appear to apply here:

["Cannot convert value of type 'AVAudioPlayer.Type' to expected argument type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201515/cannot-convert-value-of-type-avaudioplayer-type-to-expected-argument-type)

BTW, I based my singleton pattern on this article:

https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Please note that I realize that I can play a sound in my app using this code:

```
run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("MySound.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))
```

But I want to play background music in this case so the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with, though I am still not sure if this is the right way to do a singleton in swift:

```
class SharingMusicPlayer {
    static var sharingMusicPlayer = SharingMusicPlayer()
    var backgroundMusicPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?
    
    private init() {
        
    }
    
    func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(
            forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        if (url == nil) {
            print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
            return
        }
        do {
            try self.backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        } catch {
            print("Could not create audio player")
        }
        

        backgroundMusicPlayer!.numberOfLoops = -1
        backgroundMusicPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
        backgroundMusicPlayer!.play()
    }
    
    func stopBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
        self.backgroundMusicPlayer!.stop()
    }
}
```

Then this is how I would call the functions to start and stop the music:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,
                                    with event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */
   for touch: AnyObject in touches {
      //1
      let location = touch.location(in:self)
      //2
      let theNode = self.atPoint(location)

      //... 
       
      if theNode.name == playMusicButton!.name {
           print("The \(playMusicButton!.name!) is touched ")
          SharingMusicPlayer.sharingMusicPlayer.playBackgroundMusic(
            filename: "BeethovenPianoSonataNr15InDmajorOp28Pastoral.mp3")
      }

       if theNode.name == stopMusicButton!.name {
            print("The \(stopMusicButton!.name!) is touched ")
           SharingMusicPlayer.sharingMusicPlayer.stopBackgroundMusic()
       }
   }
```

Please note that the above buttons are in `SpriteKit` so they are different than the usual `UIButton` objects in `Main.storyboard`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing it the `type` AVAudioPlayer when you need to pass an `instance` of `AVAudioPlayer`. This should work I guess:

Change

```
static let sharingMusicPlayer = SharingMusicPlayer(backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer)
```

to

```
static let sharingMusicPlayer
    = SharingMusicPlayer(backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer())
```

**Update**

This is the full code that compiles at my end

```
class SharingMusicPlayer {
    static let sharingMusicPlayer
        = SharingMusicPlayer(backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer())
    let backgroundMusicPlayer : AVAudioPlayer

    private init(backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer) {
        self.backgroundMusicPlayer = backgroundMusicPlayer
    }

    func playMusic() {
        // open and play an mp3 file...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but these are the errors I get if I try that:  `~/SharingMusicPlayer.swift:19:79: Cannot convert value of type 'AVAudioPlayer.Type' to expected argument type 'AVAudioPlayer'

~/SharingMusicPlayer.swift:19:92: Missing argument for parameter #2 in call

~/SharingMusicPlayer.swift:23:54: Expected ',' separator

~/SharingMusicPlayer.swift:23:54: Unnamed parameters must be written with the empty name '_'`

Comment: @user8128167 - thats odd, see my update, it's your full code with my small change that compiles fine at my end.